# How to use webpack HASH filename and dotnet publish?

Tags: javascript, c, asp.net-mvc, webpack, .net-core

I am using dotnet core for my backend website, using MVC webpage (index.cshtml) and angular2 for my application.

My problem is that with every new release, users are obtaining the old javascript files, because my index.cshtml looks like this

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <my-app>
        <div class="container text-md-center">
            <div class="mb-1">Loading application, please wait...</div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </my-app>

    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/webpack.bundle.js"></script>
    @if (ViewBag.Environment != "Production")
    {
        <script defer type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/app-style.bundle.js"></script>
        <script defer type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/vendor-style.bundle.js"></script>
    }

    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/builders.bundle.js"></script>
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am also using webpack to bundle all my typescript, html views etc.

In my dotnet publish "prepublish" tags, i am getting webpack to run to create a production build, as below

```
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm run build" ],
}
```

And in my package.json file, "npm run build" is defined as so.

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf node_modules doc dist && npm cache clean",
    "clean-install": "npm run clean && npm install",
    "clean-start": "npm run clean-install && npm start",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --progress --profile",
    "debug": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail",
    "lint": "tslint --force \"wwwroot/app/**/*.ts\"",
    "docs": "typedoc --options typedoc.json wwwroot/app/app.component.ts",
    "postinstall": "npm run"
},
```

This is all very well, but since dotnet publish copies the files to a new location, and webpack runs before the copy... How can i update my index.cshtml file to include the hash tags for script files, without changing the actual index.cshtml file, because obviously that is checked in and dont want to release a new version everytime i publish (as it should be more of a template)

Any help much appreciated!

**EDIT**
Here is my actual webpack.config.js file

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;

/**
 * Env
 * Get npm lifecycle event to identify the environment
 */
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTestWatch = ENV === 'test-watch';
var isTest = ENV === 'test' || isTestWatch;
var isProd = ENV === 'build';

console.log(isProd ? 'Production build...' : 'Debug build...');

// Webpack Config
module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {

    /**
     * Config
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html
     * This is the object where all configuration gets set
     */
    var config = {};

    /**
     * Devtool
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
     * Type of sourcemap to use per build type
     */
    if (isProd) {
        config.devtool = 'source-map';
    }
    else if (isTest) {
        config.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
    }
    else {
        config.devtool = 'source-map';
    }

    /**
     * Entry
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
     */
    config.entry = isTest ? {} : {
        'polyfills':       './wwwroot/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor':          './wwwroot/vendor.ts',
        'builders':        './wwwroot/builders.ts',
        'app':             './wwwroot/app.ts',
        'vendor-style':    './wwwroot/style/vendor-style.ts',
        'app-style':       './wwwroot/style/app-style.ts'
    };

    /**
     * Output
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
     */
    config.output = isTest ? {} : {
        path: './wwwroot/dist',
        publicPath: './dist/',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].bundle.js.map',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    };

    /**
     * Resolve
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
     */
    config.resolve = {
        // only discover files that have those extensions
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    };

    var atlOptions = '';
    if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
        // awesome-typescript-loader needs to output inlineSourceMap for code coverage to work with source maps.
        atlOptions = 'inlineSourceMap=true&sourceMap=false';
    }

    /**
     * Loaders
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
     * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html
     * This handles most of the magic responsible for converting modules
     */
    config.module = {
        rules: [
            // .ts files for TypeScript
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader?' + atlOptions,
                exclude: [isTest ? /\.(e2e)\.ts$/ : /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader'] })
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'] })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            hash: 'sha512',
                            digest: 'hex',
                            name: '[hash].[ext]'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        options: {
                            bypassOnDebug: true,
                            optimizationLevel: 7,
                            interlaced: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            prefix: 'font/',
                            limit: 5000,
                            publicPath: '../dist/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 10000,
                            mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
                            publicPath: '../dist/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 10000,
                            mimetype: 'image/svg+xml'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    if (!isTest || !isTestWatch) {
        // tslint support
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            loader: 'tslint-loader'
        });
    }

    /**
     * Plugins
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html
     */
    config.plugins = [

        // Define env variables to help with builds
        // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            // Environment helpers
            'process.env': {
                ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
            }
        }),

        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            debug: true,
            options: {
                /**
                 * Apply the tslint loader as pre/postLoader
                 * Reference: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
                 */
                tslint: {
                    emitErrors: false,
                    failOnHint: false
                },

                // htmlLoader
                htmlLoader: {
                    minimize: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: false,
                    caseSensitive: true,
                    customAttrSurround: [ [/#/, /(?:)/], [/\*/, /(?:)/], [/\[?\(?/, /(?:)/] ],
                    customAttrAssign: [ /\)?\]?=/ ]
                },

                // postcss
                postcss: [
                    autoprefixer({
                        browsers: ['last 2 version']
                    })
                ]
            }
        })
    ];

    if (!isTest && !isTestWatch) {
        config.plugins.push(
            new ForkCheckerPlugin(),

            // Generate common chunks if necessary
            // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html
            // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
            new CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: ['app', 'builders', 'vendor', 'polyfills', 'webpack'],
                minChunks: Infinity
            }),

            // Extract css files
            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
            // Disabled when in test mode or not in build mode
            new ExtractTextPlugin({
                filename: '[name].css',
                disable: !isProd
            })
        );
    }

    // Add build specific plugins
    if (isProd) {
        config.plugins.push(
            // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#noerrorsplugin
            // Only emit files when there are no errors
            new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),

            // // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin
            // // Dedupe modules in the output
            // new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

            // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
            // Minify all javascript, switch loaders to minimizing mode
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                sourceMap: true,
                mangle: {
                    keep_fnames: true
                }
            })
        );
    }

    return config;
}();
```

Comment: maybe this helps http://michaco.net/blog/Angular4GettingHashedWebpackBundlesWorkingInASPNETCoreMVC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer... Someone else has added a nice guide

https://scottaddie.com/2015/12/14/a-practical-approach-to-cache-busting-with-webpack-and-asp-net-5/

Comment: Could you add some information here? Links become dead eventually

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I'm not using this approach myself. I tried it out but the multiple matching files issue was a pain. Leaving the answer in case it helps someone in a different situation.

Another way to do this is to:

- Configure webpack with [name].[chunkhash].js and [name].[chunkhash].css, to make the regexes less likely to missfire
- Write code to supplement Bundle.Include that is more flexible, eg supporting {hash} in addition to {version} and *, probably using regular expressions
- Make sure that if there are multiple files matching your regular expression, you take the most recent one!
- Set up your files as bundles in BundleConfig.cs
- on your .cshtml pages, use Scripts.Render and Styles.Render to pull in the correct underlying files for each bundle

Here is some sample code that finds the matching physical files despite the hash name. I'll leave integrating it into BundleConfig.cs as an exercise for the reader, as it may be different depending on what else you have going on. Also it needs changing to get only the most recent file.

```
    private static string ReplaceHash(string pathWithHash)
    {
        var i = pathWithHash.LastIndexOf('/');
        var virtualPath = pathWithHash.Substring(0, i);
        var physicalPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(virtualPath);
        var fileName = pathWithHash.Substring(i + 1);

        if (!Directory.Exists(physicalPath))
        {
            throw new FfcException(string.Format("Bundle path '{0}' not found", pathWithHash));
        }
        var re = new Regex(fileName
            .Replace(".", @"\.")
            .Replace("{hash}", @"([0-9a-fA-F]+)")
            .Replace("{version}", @"(\d+(?:\.\d+){1,3})")
            .Replace("*", @".*")
            , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
        );

        fileName = fileName
            .Replace("{hash}", "*")
            .Replace("{version}", "*");

        var matchingFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(physicalPath, fileName).Where(file => re.IsMatch(file)).ToList();
        if (matchingFiles.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new FfcException(string.Format("Bundle resource '{0}' not found", pathWithHash));
        }
        if (matchingFiles.Count > 1)
        {
            // TODO: need to pick the most recently created matching file
            throw new FfcException(string.Format("Ambiguous Bundle resource '{0}' requested", pathWithHash));
        }
        var matchingPhysicalFile = matchingFiles[0];
        var matchingVirtualFile = matchingPhysicalFile.Replace(physicalPath + "\\", virtualPath + "/");
        return matchingVirtualFile;
    }
```